# Как инъектятся параметры поиска в Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

Смотрю на код в Yii2 и не совсем понимаю, как в $dataProvider попадает обновленный запрос:

```
class ScheduleSearch extends Schedule
{
    // ... 

    public function search($params)
    {
        $query = Schedule::find();                           // 1

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,                               // 2
        ]);

        if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
            return $dataProvider;                            // 3
        }

        $query->andFilterWhere([                             // 4
            'id' => $this->id,
            'play_date' => $this->play_date,
        ]);

        return $dataProvider;                                // 5
    }
}
```

Вот в **(1)** определена переменная *$query* и на ее основе создан экземпляр *ActiveDataProvider* **(2)**.

В **(4)** начинается магия: изменяется *$query* внутри *$dataProvider* и не понятно, как именно действие **(4)** затрагивает *$dataProvider*. Если в *$dataProvider* передается значение по ссылке, то как это формально выражается?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$dataProvider` содержит в себе `$query`, в **4** мы изменяем состояние `$query`, что в свою очередь будет влиять на результат работы `$dataProvider`, т.к. `$query`, на основе которого мы создали в **2** *ActiveDataProvider* и который ме меняем в **4** - это один и тот же объект. Т.е., да он был передан в конструктор *по ссылке*.

Что Вы подразумеваете под формальным выражением? В PHP, начиная (вроде бы как) с 5ой версии, *все объекты по умолчанию передаются по ссылке*.

Т.е. никакой "магии" нет. Результат работы `$dataProvider` зависит от состояния `$query`, а в **4** мы меняем его состояние, что в свою очередь влияет на итоговый результат работы `$dataProvider`.